# al remplazar un fragment por otro me da error en el nuevo fragment a insertar

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

tengo una actividad que contiene un fragment y un boton fuera de dicho fragment, necesito crear un evento que, al dar clic en el boton, me remplace dicho fragment por otro. Aqui les dejo un pedazo del codigo para que vean, el fragment "**Fragment_Temas**" me da error.

```
    two.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragment_manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment_manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace( R.id.layout_fragment, Fragment_Temas);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes instanciar el fragment para poder remplazar al otro fragment.

Proba esto:

```
two.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

      Fragment_Temas fragmentTemas = new Fragment_Temas();

      FragmentManager fragment_manager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment_manager.beginTransaction();
      transaction.replace( R.id.layout_fragment, fragmentTemas);
      transaction.commit();
   }
});
```

Comment: ya lo intente, y me da igual error..gracias

Comment: podrias agregar el error que te sale? asi seria mas facil resolver el problema

Comment: el error era el mismo, lo acabo de resolver, estaba cargando la libreria q no era, ----->import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;<---- cambie a esta y ya...gracias